# how to colorize a string/word in html/jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to colorize a string/word in HTML. I found a response here - but I am having trouble understanding how to convert to use the function more than once..

http://jsfiddle.net/8VDm4/

```
<div id="arch" style="font-size: 40px">First Word work fine</div>
<div id="arch" style="font-size: 40px">Second time - does not work</div>



var colours = ["#635636", "#FF00C0", "#990066", "#FF9966", "#996666", "#00FF00", "#CC9933"], 
idx;

$(function() {
var div = $('#arch'); 
var chars = div.text().split('');
div.html('');     
for(var i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
    idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
    var span = $('<span>' + chars[i] + '</span>').css("color", colours[idx]);
    div.append(span);
}
});
```

How to create a function that I can call multiple times in a HTML?

Comment: you can only have one element with a particular id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one element with a particular `id`. Replace your `id` with `class` (or add a particular class to elements) like follows

```
<div class="arch" style="font-size: 40px">First Word work fine</div>
<div class="arch" style="font-size: 40px">Second time - does not work</div>
```

**javascript**

```
//code has been update in response of observation made by adeneo, thanks adeneo

var colours = ["#635636", "#FF00C0", "#990066", "#FF9966", "#996666", "#00FF00", "#CC9933"],
    idx;

$(function () {
    $('.arch').each(function () {
        var div = $(this),
            chars = div.text().split(''),
            span = '';

        div.html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colours.length);
            span = span + $('<div>').append($('<span>' + chars[i] + '</span>').css('color', colours[idx])).html();
        }
        div.append(span);
    });
});
```

I've added some code to avoid frequent update of DOM

Comment: That surely can't work, `div.text()` and `div.html()` would work on both elements at the same time ?

Comment: I tried with making minimum changes to the code (replace id with class) and it worked (in firefox. checking in other browsers)

Comment: update: works in google chrome and internet explorer too, so probably jQuery is doing some magic or identifying the collection and working on one element at a time?

Comment: I don't believe you, show me it working in a fiddle (tip: you can borrow Jay's fiddle, it has the same errors.)

Comment: please believe me :D I see colorized strings in jay's fiddle too

Comment: That's great, but look at what the strings say, they both say "First Word work fineSecond time - does not work", in other words, you've both joined the text from multiple elements together.

Comment: Ok, that's right! I didn't pay attention to that. Thanks for the closer look and pointing out (y). Updating the answer

Comment: @user1337450 checkout adeneo's jsfiddle. That's some nice code!

Answer (score 0):

Change the id's on your div's to classes -

```
<div class="arch" style="font-size: 40px">First Word work fine</div>
<div class="arch" style="font-size: 40px">Second time - does not work</div>
```

And then change your selector in your jQuery -

```
var div = $('.arch');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8VDm4/2/

Answer (score 0):

As Ejay has mentioned, it doesn't work because you used ID's. You can only use an ID once on a page. What you want to use are classes.

Markup:

```
<div class="arch">You content</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var div = $('.arch');
```

I've also updated the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8VDm4/1/